# evernote/android-job - how to schedule and run periodically

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher, android-job

I have tried all the below methods from [evernote-android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job). Seems the schedulePeriodicJob method is running in some interval and the scheduleAdvancedJob method run only once.

Help me how to set values for setExecutionWindow, setExact and setPeriodic with some example?

```
private void scheduleAdvancedJob() {
    PersistableBundleCompat extras = new PersistableBundleCompat();
    extras.putString("key", "Hello world");

    int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .setExecutionWindow(30_000L, 40_000L)
            .setBackoffCriteria(5_000L, JobRequest.BackoffPolicy.EXPONENTIAL)
            .setRequiresCharging(true)
            .setRequiresDeviceIdle(false)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(JobRequest.NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setExtras(extras)
            .setRequirementsEnforced(true)
            .setUpdateCurrent(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
}

private void schedulePeriodicJob() {
    int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5))
            .build()
            .schedule();
}

private void scheduleExactJob() {
    int jobId = new JobRequest.Builder(DemoSyncJob.TAG)
            .setExact(20_000L)
            .build()
            .schedule();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same schenario and used this one and get success. you can also try it.

```
public class RunFSJob extends Job {

    public static final String TAG = "JOB_FOR_START_SIGNARSERVICE";

    @Override
    @NonNull
    protected Result onRunJob(@NonNull Params params) {

        try {

            deleteCache(getContext().getApplicationContext());

            getContext().getApplicationContext().startService(new Intent(getContext().getApplicationContext(), SignalRService.class));

            Log.v("schedulePeriodicJob(15)", "JOB Done");

            cancel();

            Log.v("schedulePeriodicJob(15)", "JOB cancled");

            schedulePeriodicJob();

            Log.v("schedulePeriodicJob(15)", "JOB scheduled again from RunFSJob");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Job.Result.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

- First of all use periodic job and schedule the same job everytime from onRunJob() method. you have to cancel the last job ,too.
- Hope it will help you.